# ModuleNotFoundError using Flask

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a Flask api :

```
app.py
routes
-> __init__.py
-> myobject.py
```

```
# app.py
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api
from routes import MyObject

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

api.add_resource(MyObject, '/')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

```
# __init__.py
from myobject import MyObject
```

```
# myobject.py
from flask_restful import Resource


class MyObject(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return {'hello': 'world'}
```

When I run my application (`python app.py`), I get a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myobject'`
I don't understand why python can't find my module `myobject`. Is there something i'm missing in my `__init__.py`

Comment: Your cases are all over the place `myobject`, `MyObject`, `myObject`. Also, are you really about to build an app with something named `myobject`? Surely there is a better name.

Comment: Change `from myObject import MyObject` to `from myobject import MyObject`, since your file is named `myobject.py`.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Indeed, my object are not named like this for my app. I just renamme to have a minimal reproducible example. My copy paste on stackoverflow miss one uppercase, but on my code all is fine

Comment: That's not good. You are taking code that has problems, rewriting it to have different problems, and asking us to help you with alleged first code problems. This is just wasting everybody's time. I knew you did something like that because your error is wrong for this code.

Comment: My apologies for that typo, I edited the question for no further confusion

Comment: So, you're saying you have everything setup JUST like that and you are still getting the error? If so, you have big problems, because that setup is right.

Comment: I see your problem `from .myobject import MyObject` try that.

Comment: I confirm this is the setup I have. I agree that should work, i'm here cause I ran out of explainations. Here is a github repo if you want to clone it and try by yourself : https://github.com/Portevent/InvalidImportError

Comment: :/ I said it first (twice)

Comment: I upvoted both anwser, but can't accept both :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `__init__.py`, it also needs the relative import **or** absolute import path in order to work correctly.

```py
# __init__.py

# relative import
from .myobject import MyObject

# absolute import
from routes.myobject import MyObject
```

In another approach, you can write to import MyObject more specifically like this and leave `__init__.py` an empty file.

```py
# app.py
# ...

from routes.myobject import MyObject

# ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your speculation. As said in comment on question, I made a typo posting the code. The right name is def `myobject`, but that is not the cause of the problem. I tried your another approach, but it doesn't solve either. Putting MyObject directly inside `__init__.py` confirm me that the app run fine. So the issue is located between `__init__.py` and my file `myobject.py`. Is Flask overriding some Python module behavior ?

Comment: You can try refactoring the import part in app.py and leave __init__.py an empty file.

Comment: That fixed the issue. I'll try to see what I did wrong with `__init__.py`. But until then, that solution works

Comment: I updated my answer to include the relative and absolute import path.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem is due to your app running in the "main" directory and your import residing in a sub directory. Basically your app thinks you are trying to import "/main/myobject.py" instead of "/main/routes/myobject.py"

Change your import in `__init__` to `from .myobject import MyObject`

The `.` means "this directory" (essentially).